# GLSL won't accept my implicit cast

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, glsl, linker-errors

I'm learning OpenGL 3.3, using some tutorials (http://opengl-tutorial.org). In the tutorial I'm using, there is a vertex shader which does the following:

**Tutorial Shader source**

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

}
```

Yet, when I try to emulate the same behavior in my application, I get the following:

`error: implicit cast from "vec4" to "vec3"`.

After seeing this, I wasn't sure if it was because I was using 4.2 version shaders as opposed to 3.3, so changed everything to match what the author had been using, still receiving the same error afterward.

So, I changed my shader to do this:

**My (latest) Source**

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
    vec4 a = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1);    

    gl_Position.xyz = MVP * a;
}
```

Which, of course, still produces the same error.

Does anyone know why this is the case, as well as what a solution might be to this? I'm not sure if it could be my calling code (which I've posted, just in case).

---

**Calling Code**

```
static const GLfloat T_VERTEX_BUF_DATA[] = 
{
    // x, y z
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};

static const GLushort T_ELEMENT_BUF_DATA[] = 
{ 0, 1, 2 };

void TriangleDemo::Run(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLuint matrixID = glGetUniformLocation(mProgramID, "MVP");

    glUseProgram(mProgramID);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mMVP[0][0]); // This sends our transformation to the MVP uniform matrix, in the currently bound vertex shader 

    const GLuint vertexShaderID = 0;

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexShaderID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        vertexShaderID, // Specify the ID of the shader to point to (in this case, the shader is built in to GL, which will just produce a white triangle)
        3,              // Specify the number of indices per vertex in the vertex buffer  
        GL_FLOAT,       // Type of value the vertex buffer is holding as data
        GL_FALSE,       // Normalized? 
        0,              // Amount of stride
        (void*)0 );     // Offset within the array buffer

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); //0 => start index of the buffer, 3 => number of vertices

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexShaderID);
}

void TriangleDemo::Initialize(void)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVertexArrayID);

    glBindVertexArray(mVertexArrayID);

    glGenBuffers(1, &mVertexBuffer);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexBuffer);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(T_VERTEX_BUF_DATA), T_VERTEX_BUF_DATA, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    mProgramID = LoadShaders("v_Triangle", "f_Triangle");

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f); // field of view, aspect ratio (4:3), 0.1 units near, to 100 units far

    glm::mat4 view  = glm::lookAt(
                                glm::vec3(4, 3, 3), // Camera is at (4, 3, 3) in world space
                                glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), // and looks at the origin
                                glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)  // this is the up vector - the head of the camera is facing upwards. We'd use (0, -1, 0) to look upside down
                            );

    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f); // set model matrix to identity matrix, meaning the model will be at the origin

    mMVP            = projection * view * model;
```

}

**Notes**

- I'm in Visual Studio 2012
- I'm using [Shader Maker](http://cg.in.tu-clausthal.de/teaching/shader_maker/index.shtml) for the GLSL editing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say what's wrong with the tutorial code.

In "My latest source" though, there's

```
gl_Position.xyz = MVP * a;
```

which looks weird because you're assigning a `vec4` to a `vec3`.

---

EDIT

I can't reproduce your problem.

I have used a trivial fragment shader for testing...

```
#version 330 core

void main()
{
}
```

**Testing "Tutorial Shader source"**:

```
3.3.11762 Core Profile Context
Log: Vertex shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.

Log: Fragment shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.

Log: Vertex shader(s) linked, fragment shader(s) linked.
```

**Testing "My latest source"**:

```
3.3.11762 Core Profile Context
Log: Vertex shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.
 WARNING: 0:11: warning(#402) Implicit truncation of vector from size 4 to size 3.

Log: Fragment shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.

Log: Vertex shader(s) linked, fragment shader(s) linked.
```

And the warning goes away after replacing `gl_Position.xyz` with `gl_Position`.

---

What's your setup? Do you have a correct version of OpenGL context? Is glGetError() silent?

Finally, are your GPU drivers up-to-date?

Comment: Your first mention was probably the main cause of the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I've had problems with some GPUs (ATi ones, I believe) not liking integer literals when it expects a float. Try changing

```
gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);
```

To

```
gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1.0);
```

Comment: I've had that on OpenGL ES 2 (WebGL), but never on 3.3 Core. (I'm on a Radeon)

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this error message on an ATI Radeon HD 7900 with latest drivers installed while compiling some sample code associated with the book "3D Engine Design for Virtual Globes" (http://www.virtualglobebook.com).

Here is the original fragment shader line:
`fragmentColor = mix(vec3(0.0, intensity, 0.0), vec3(intensity, 0.0, 0.0), (distanceToContour < dF));`

The solution is to cast the offending Boolean expression into float, as in:
`fragmentColor = mix(vec3(0.0, intensity, 0.0), vec3(intensity, 0.0, 0.0), float(distanceToContour < dF));`

The manual for mix (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl) states

> For the variants of mix where a is genBType, elements for which a[i] is false, the result for that
>   element is taken from x, and where a[i] is true, it will be taken from y.

So, since a Boolean blend value *should* be accepted by the compiler without comment, I think this should go down as an AMD/ATI driver issue.